# Chef windows_package not able to do silent install; Asking user inputs

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, chef-windows

I am using Chef windows_package to install Software called Oxygen in Windows. I am expecting it to install silently without asking any user inputs(take all defaults) but its launching install4j wizard and asking for user inputs like "Please Select your Language"

This is the chef recipe

```
windows_package 'Notepad++ Installer 64-bit x64' do
  source 'http://mirror.oxygenxml.com/InstData/Editor/Windows64/VM/oxygen-64bit.exe'
  installer_type :custom
  options '/S'
end
```

Running this recipe launching an install4j window to choose language. I don't want user to enter any input, instead everything should be provided through chef recipe and perform installation.

[image]
Am I missing anything in options here?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google shows they don't support the `/S` option for silent installs but instead have their own system. https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18/ug-editor/references/install-installer-command-line-reference.html covers all the details.

Comment: Yes, I see they support  "oxygen.exe -q ". I was wondering if we could use windows_package for this by any chance.   I am able to do this using chef execute, by executing the .exe file with -q option.

Comment: As you can see in your own code, there is an `options` property. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

We have used **windows_package** to install an application with response file like this:

```
windows_package 'theapp' do
  source 'D:\Path\To\Source\Setup.exe'
  options '-s -f1D:\Path\To\Source\theapp.iss' \
              -f2D:\Path\To\Source\theapp.log'
 installer_type :installshield
end
```

Regards